# JavaFX Dialog.showAndWait() in Button's MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED handler cancels the following MOUSE_RELEASED and MOUSE_CLICKED events

Tags: java, validation, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent

Coding problem (is it a bug?) generalized:

If user interaction, in the form of `Dialog.showAndWait()`, is used inside `MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED` of a `Button`, it seems that the following `MouseEvents` (`MOUSE_RELEASED`, `MOUSE_CLICKED`) are "cancelled" somehow. No button action is called, visually, the button is locked in "pressed", or "pressed/armed" pseudoclass.

Use case (how I encountered the problem): I am developing a more complex table-like control in JavaFX. I need some **validation** of individual simple controls (like `TextField` etc.) to prevent illegal content. To be more precise: I need a **validation of a group of controls**, practically a "row" of different controls (in a table-like arrangement), i.e. the validity depends on the content (value) of more controls of different type (textfields, combos, checkboxes etc). My idea was that it would be fine to do the validation in `focusedProperty` `ChangeListener`. Simply: illegal state is OK once the control still has the focus and the user is using the control; once the user is "leaving" the control (focus is lost), it could be the right time to do the validation. Or in my case precisely: validation should be done when the focus is moved **outside the validated group/row of controls** (to other row, other controls etc.). The trouble is that when the validation uses **user interaction** using modal dialog - `javafx.scene.control.Dialog`, it spoils somehow the `MouseEvent` handling in the control, which gained the focus (by mouse clicking) from the validated control.

See a very simple demonstration (not of the per row validation but) of the fact that running Dialog.showAndWait() during `MOUSE_PRESSED` event processing spoils (cancels?) the next MouseEvent processing:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MouseEventsTest extends Application {    
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField("Test");
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
            if (!nv) {
                System.out.println("TextField: focus lost");
                (new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Focus lost", ButtonType.OK)).showAndWait();
            }        
        });        

        Button button = new Button("Button 1");
        button.setStyle("-fx-pressed-base: red;"); // to visually demonstrate "pressed" pseudocl. lock (in Modena)
        // to debug MouseEvents:
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> {
            if (e.getEventType() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) {   // MOUSE_MOVED events too frequent and irrelevant
                System.out.println("Button 1 - MouseEvent handled: " + e.getEventType());
            }
        });
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            System.out.println("Button 1 action");
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, button, new Button("Button 2"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test App");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Originally, the `TextField` has the focus. Click the `Button` 1: focus on the `TextField` is lost (because button's `MousePressed` event leads to `requstFocus()` on that button, which leads to "focus lost event" - `focusedProperty` change to false - in the `TextField`), the dialog is shown, click OK. As you can see the debuging info from the `MouseEvent` handler of `Button` 1, `MOUSE_RELEASED` event and `MOUSE_CLICKED` event are not caught in the handler. Visually, **the button is locked in the pressed state** (red highlight used to demonstrate).

Then try: click `Button` 2, `Button` 2 gets the focus, then click `Button` 1 - `MOUSE_RELEASED` and `MOUSE_CLICKED` events are handled OK in this case. Nothing is probably "interrupted" by dialog `.showAndWait()`.

**EDIT:**

For debugging purposes I added `Dialog.showAndWait()` directly to `Button` 1 `addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED...)`, having removed it from `focusProperty`  `ChangeListener`, and the behavior is the same, but surprisingly, the button is locked not in "pressed", but in "pressed+armed" state.

**Is it a bug?**

**Or is it a general rule never to do any user interaction during pending MouseEvents?**

**If so, what is the standard correct solution, or better solution for validation or other user interaction inside MouseEvent handler?**

Tested in JavaFX 11.

The sample code is of course only a very simplified demo...

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html

Comment: @fabian Thanks but this is not my solution - see the edits of the question: I need not "per component" validation, but "per group/row of more controls" validation. Furthermore controls of different type are validated (not only textfields).

Comment: hmm .. dont quite see where the "validation group" is in this example. Just the textField?

Comment: okay, see what you mean (I think at least ;) - the button's pressed state is not released when the alert is shown from a focusHandler of a different control (all fine if invoked from the button itself) .. hmm, might be a bug, not entire certain, though

Comment: I can't say why the focus is getting messed up, but you probably want to separate the validation of your model from the UI anyhow, to determine if people could drink (legally): ```legalDrinkingProperty().bind(Bindings.greaterThanOrEqual(19, ageProperty()).and(Bindings.notNull(driversLicenseProperty());``` You could then bind legalDrinkingProperty to the background/border color of your row.

Comment: @kleopatra sorry for unclear question (edited to generalized version). See my edit: for debugging purposes I added Dialog.showAndWait() directly to Button 1 addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED...), and the behavior is similar, with some surprising difference...